# How to disable transition for testing Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

According to the doc [Testing your Compose layout][1], we can disable transition as following:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = AndroidComposeTestRule<MyActivity>(disableTransitions = true)
```

However, there's no such parameter available in AndroidComposeTestRule. Testing with Snackbars is failing using SnackbarHost since it has animations. Is there a way to disable transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [review.googlesource.com](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1452775), the parameter `disableTransitions` is not longer available in AndroidComposeTestRule. We can use `DisableTransitionsTestRule` to disable transitions.

Comment: I am not sure why that answer was accepted, is it not marked internal? `@InternalTestingApi`

Comment: @Maurycy It was publicly available and not marked internal when the question was posted. It probably is now.

Comment: For a similar issue, I tried `composeTestRule.mainClock.advanceTimeBy(1000)` to move the clock forward 1 second until the animation is finished.
Example on official docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#disable-autosync

Comment: is this real? I can't find `DisableTransitionsTestRule()` in any of the android apis?